# How being unable to settle all disputes makes it possible to settle many disputes?

Tags: logic

I'm reading Wieland's: *Infinite Regress Arguments*. In here:

> [image]

I don't understand how the fail to settle all disputes implies that one couldn't settle many of them. The only possibility I see is using the meaning of *"all"* as *"all disputes of a certain class"* as such that this class does not contain all possible disputes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He doesn't say that from not being able to settle all disputes follows that one can settle many disputes. He merely notes that it *allows* for that.

His point is that ¬∀<sub>d∈D</sub>[S(d)] is weaker than ¬∃<sub>d∈D</sub>[S(d)], since the first allows for ∃<sub>d∈D</sub>[S(d)] (although this does not necessarily follow), while the second doesn't. (I use D for the set of all disputes, S(d) for 'it is possible to settle d').

Comment: Does ¬∀d∈D[S(d)] means: ¬S(d1)∧¬S(d2)∧¬S(d3)∧...∧¬S(dn) or one to *evaluate* the value of ∀d∈D[S(d)] first and then apply the negation?

Comment: @Vÿska no, ¬∀d∈D[S(d)] means. It is _not_ true that _for all_ d in D holds that S(d). From [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) follows then that there is _at least one_ d in D for which S(d) does _not_ hold.

Comment: Got it. It was more or less as I suggested in the second case. Although that view was kinda skewed.